# How can make the scope of $controller another controller scope

Tags: angularjs

I have application with two modules
1- projects
2- documents

each project has many documents and when I select one project in the projects table I want to display its documents

for each module I made service.js and controller.js
in the document controller.js there is function that get the suitable documents info form data base and fill it in document table

I am using this function to get data to my table

```
var documentCtrl = this;
documentCtrl.callServer = function callServer(projectId) {

        return documentsService.getDocuments(projectId).then(function(result){
                 documentCtrl.displayed = result.documents;
        });
    }
```

in the project table I want when select any project to get its documents and display it in document table

```
var projectCtrl = this;
projectCtrl.toggleSelection = function indexof(row){

  var documentController = $controller('documentsListController',{
      $scope : 'what I have to use here??' 
  });

  documentController.callServer(row.projectId);
}
```

when I call this function from projectCtrl the object documentCtrl.displayed is filled but the table  stay empty

so I don't want to communicat between controllers all what I need is to call

```
callServer(projectId) {

        return documentsService.getDocuments(projectId).then(function(result){
                 documentCtrl.displayed = result.documents;
        });
```

and fill the documentCtrl.displayed with suitable value and display it in this table

```
<div id="documentsList" ng-controller="documentsListController as doc" >
<tr ng-repeat="row in doc.displayed">
        <td>{{row.documentId}}</td>
        <td>{{row.documentName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.documentExtension}}</td>
</tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible ways to communicate between controllers.

- services
- events
- watchers

The easiest one - Services. You have called `documentsService` you can save returned data to the variable inside that service. And it will be avaible across all controllers in which that service will be injected.

```
var documentCtrl = this;
documentCtrl.callServer = function callServer(projectId) {

    return documentsService.getDocuments(projectId).then(function(result){
             documentCtrl.displayed = result.documents;
             documentsService.documents = result.documets;
    });
}
```

And just inject service to second controller, once it will be called in first one, the result will be available in second too.